# Embedded Neo4j Java Node & Relationship Objects to JSON

Tags: java, json, neo4j

Am using Neo4j 2.0.1 as Embedded db in java application. Querying in java and getting Nodes and Relationship objects. How can we convert this to JSON format ? So that it will be fed to d3.js for visualization. Is there any Neo4j Java API methods exists ?

Comment: i usually just fill a list of maps from the nodes and rel-props and render them to json with jackson or Gson, see https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-movies/blob/master/src/main/java/org/neo4j/example/movies/MovieService.java#L71

Comment: thanks for the code example Michael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create [domain entities](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-entities.html) from your nodes and annotate them with [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) annotations. Converting a pojo to JSON is as easy as

```
ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String json = ow.writeValueAsString(object);
```

Comment: Thanks for the methodology. Will try this way.